# Integer factorization: does $az + by$ helps?

Tags: factoring, prime-factorization

I am trying to find solutions for integer factorization problem. And particularly I am curries in RSA cracking.

I came to the next equation:

$$az + by = \frac{c}{x}$$

- $c$ is the number that I am trying to factor.
- $x$ one of the two possible solutions(because it's RSA, $c$ been chosen that way)
- $a,b$ relatively small positive integer constants that I know their value
- $z,y$ positive integer variables

Can this be any useful for me?

Comment: @Joffan I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: The problem of efficiently factoring a very large number $N$, even in the special case where $N$ is known to be a product of two primes, has a large literature. There has been progress, but (unless NSA is keeping it secret) factorization appears to be difficult. Progress, when it comes, will probably involve new tools.

Comment: @AndréNicolas from time to time it just catch me, that need to try and solve this. And I am aware for the difficulty of this problem and the probability of my success solving it. In any case, I enjoy trying. In this particular question, I just wonder if I can use this information that I found to reduce the difficulty of the original problem, may be just by little bit, or $\frac{c}{x}$ can just be replaced by any number and this is completely useless.

Comment: If it interests you, it is fine to pursue it. Exploration may produce an algorithm more efficient than the "try everything which is not obviously too big." Beating the industrial-grade factoring algorithms will be tough.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I made some progress in my search. Can you please looks at it [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118529/integer-factorization-possible-progress).

Comment: something about factorization is, it doesn't seem to play well with 'conventional' mathematics of division, multiplication and division unless you see that you cannot go further...

Answer (score -1):

Take $N=XY$ and imagine that each number is written using the division algorithm in terms of some base $B$.  Then you get $Bz+r=(Bx+a)(By+b)$.  Where $r$ is congruent to $ab$ mod $B$, and $N$, $X$, $Y$ are relatively prime to $B$. A little algebra reduces this to $z=Bxy+ay+bx+m$.  Now you have reduced your search area for trial division by a factor of $B$, except that you have to multiply it by the totient function of $B$.  Thus the fastest you can get (on the surface) with this method is using the reduced residue systems of primorials.  The rough best choice for $B$ is around the third or fourth root of $N$.  You want to pick $B$ small enough that the factors you seek are not in the reduced residue system or else the equation collapses to trial division over the reduced residue system, that is roughly speaking trial division.  The best value for $B$ is not knowable simply as a function of $N$ unless you decide to shift gears whenever $ax+by$ is greater than $B$ by choosing $B$ from some easy to use sequence like the primorials.  At worst you have to check $\phi(n)$ places at each level.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/39599) to improve your answer.